# How do I pass a date in the Java Date format to cURL (PHP)?

Tags: java, php, android, curl, parse-platform

There is an Android application, it sends to the server through Parse.com one of the parameters in the format Date:

```
HashMap<String, Object> p = new HashMap();
p.put("created", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(f, p, v);
```

How can I pass a parameter in the same format, but only through cURL in PHP? I tried to pass a string value to the array, the server does not accept the request:

```
array('created'=>'Sun Nov 12 2017 02:58:09 GMT+0300')
```

As I understand, it is necessary to pass the parameter in the form of the Date object itself, but the question is how it will look in the raw text form?

I tried to pass the Date as an array, but this server does not want to accept either:

```
array('__type'=>'Date','iso'=>'2017-11-11T12:35:39.273Z')
```

Comment: most likely as an iso date: `array('created'=>'2017-11-11T12:35:39.273Z')` but you will have to get confirmation from the "server code" owner (or some doc). Can't you use the [provided SDK](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a date to parse-server in **ISO 8601** format (with millisecond precision), as mentioned in the [REST docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#data-types).

```
{
    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
}
```

You can see an example of how this is done in the [php sdk](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php#L762).